# Why does Tinker Bell need fairy dust to fly given that she has wings?

Tags: fairy, tinker-bell

My daughter keeps asking me this good question. She is watching Disney's Tinker Bell movies, in which fairies are producing and using fairy dust to be able to fly.

Is this only the case in the Tinker Bell movies? If they have wings why would they need fairy dust to fly?

Comment: Maybe the wings are too small to support her weight and the fairy dust has the magical power to provide additional uplift ;)

Comment: @Ghanima Had similar thoughts... Fairies, the bumblebees of the magical realm? Hm... :D

Comment: Tell her its like gasoline.  Why does a car need gas if it has wheels and an engine?

Comment: Why do people need Segways when they've got legs?

Comment: Butterflies and moths have dust on their wings and if you touch them it comes of and they can't fly.could this be the same dust?.

Answer (score 26):

In the new [Disney Fairies : Tinker Bell](http://www.disney.co.uk/disney-fairies/) movies, both dust *and* wings are essential components of fairy flight.

- Without **wings,** a fairy can't fly. We see this in "[Secret of the Wings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_of_the_Wings)" where Tink wraps her wings inside her coat and crashes. It appears that it's the wings that are suffused with fairy dust. We see it falling away whenever any of the fairies fly fast.

[image]

- Without **Pixie Dust,** a fairy can't fly. We see this in "[Tinker Bell and the Lost Treasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinker_Bell_and_the_Lost_Treasure)" when Tink runs out of dust. Her wings appear to be capable of small amounts of lift (and changes in direction) but without the boost offered by Dust, the wings are solely capable of short hops, not self-powered flight.

[image]

Later, in the same film we see this damaged parchment. Although some of the words are illegible, the bottom part seems pretty clear. Without both Pixie Dust and Wings, fairies can't fly. The dust also has a secondary effect of allowing the fairy to use their inborn *magical* skills, presumably using the same A+B formula.

[image]

Comment: But this doesn't explain *why* it just says that Tinkerbell needs fairy dust (and wings) to fly, which the question states.

Comment: @wikis - Because her wings provide insufficient boost. She can't fly with them. ..

Comment: And without wings, she can't perform turns and changes of direction (easily)

Comment: Wow, @Richard, just wow.

Comment: I think if you add that to the answer it might be perfect.

Answer (score 6):

I just happened to read the original book - [one](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/peter-pan-j-m-barrie/1007393899?ean=9781588364203) of the originals, anyway - recently. It's not directly explained, but I was left with the idea that the "slightly inclined to *enbonpoint*"  Tinkerbell didn't need the fairy dust *herself* ; her fairy dust was needed for anyone *else* to fly.

ch. III *Come Away, Come Away!* :

> Of course Peter had been trifling with them, for no one can fly unless
>   the fairy dust has been blown on him. Fortunately, as we have
>   mentioned, one of his hands was messy with it, and he blew some on
>   each of them, with the most superb results.

Comment: Of course there's no indication that this restriction applies to Tinkerbell in the books

Comment: And in the original film. She seems to manufacture the stuff

Comment: @Richard: Kind of like the "dust" (actually tiny scales) from the wings of butterflies and moths.

Comment: In the film, Peter holds her wings and the dust comes off of her body; http://i.stack.imgur.com/XVbGy.gif

Answer (score 1):

In the book, fairies don't need dust.

In the Disney films, both dust and wings are necessary. I guess the dust helps the fairies to **fly** in the same way as a balloon, but that they need their wings do direct themselves.

Answer (score 0):

When a fairy applies pixie dust to themselves, they sprinkle it directly on their wings, so their wings are flying, not their bodies. The wings help them control themselves, so if they didn't have wings they would be out of control. So when a human sprinkles pixie dust on themselves, they fly out of control.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Answer (score -3):

> Fairies have wings, but their wings are to weak to carry there fat
>   bodies (or so to speak). However fairies have pixie dust to help them.
>   The dust in question lets them fly, so they have wings for the sole
>   purpose of velocity*.

*Velocity: the speed and direction of which things travel

Comment: Quote from?....

Comment: Google does not find it seem like a quote from nowhere.